# Passar valores do form para o Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Como faço para passar valores do formulário para o PHP com o Ajax?

JS (sem passar valores)

```
$(function() {
if ($('#javascript-ajax-button').length !== 0) {
    $('#javascript-ajax-button').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax(url + "/login/ajaxLogin") // ISSO É UMA URL, E NÃO UM ARQUIVO
            .done(function(result) {
                switch(result) {
                    case 'This user does not exist':
                        alert("This user does not exist");
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("Sucesso!");
                }
            })
            .fail(function() {
                // this will be executed if the ajax-call had failed
            })
            .always(function() {
                // this will ALWAYS be executed, regardless if the ajax-call was success or not
            });
    });
}
});
```

PHP

```
class Login extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        //if($this->model->isUserLoggedIn()) 
            //header('Location: ' . URL . 'me');

        $news = $this->model->latestNews();

        require APP . 'view/_templates/header.php';
        require APP . 'view/login/index.php';
        require APP . 'view/_templates/footer.php';
    }

    /**
     * AJAX-ACTION: AjaxLogin
     * TODO documentation
    */
    public function ajaxLogin()
    {
        // QUERO QUE OS VALORES SEJAM REGASTADOS AQUI

        $errors = $this->model->doLoginWithPostData($_POST['user_name'],
    $_POST['user_password']);
        // simply echo out something. A supersimple API would be possible by                echoing JSON here
        echo $errors;
    }
}
```

OBS: estou usando MVC, e o url do ajax não é para um arquivo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o  `$('SeletorParaOSeuForm').serialize()`  do Jquery para facilmente receber as informações de seu form.

**Exemplo**

```
            $.ajax({
            url: url + "/login/ajaxLogin",
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#idSeuForm').serialize(),
            success: function (obj) {
            });
```

Será enviada na requisição os valores dos campos de seu form, o nome da variável será o valor do atributo "name" de seus campos.

No seu PHP os valores podem ser resgatados da seguinte forma:

```
$_POST["seuName"]
```

aonde `seuName` é valor do atributo name do campo do form que você quer recuperar

Comment: Como faço para pegar esses dados no php?

Comment: $_POST["seuName"], aonde seuName é valor do atributo name do campo do form que você quer recuperar

Answer (score 2):

Lembre de enviar os valores do form pelo e configurar o método de envio

```
$(function() {
if ($('#javascript-ajax-button').length !== 0) {
    $('#javascript-ajax-button').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url:  "/login/ajaxLogin",
        data: {login:valor, senha: valor}) 
    .done(function(data) {
                switch(data) {
                    case 'This user does not exist':
                        alert("This user does not exist");
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("Sucesso!");
                }
            })
            .fail(function() {
                // this will be executed if the ajax-call had failed
            })
            .always(function() {
                // this will ALWAYS be executed, regardless if the ajax-call was success or not
            });
    });
}
});
```

[Jquest ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: não precisa fazer nenhuma edição no php?, poderia adequar meu código para que possa enviar os valores?

Comment: So trocar o `$_POST` pelo `this->input->post('nome')` @misakie

Comment: Mas eu não estou usando code igniter '--', aliás, nenhuma framework

Comment: @misakie hahah esse código ai tem uma cara de CI, foi mal

Comment: Poderia me deixar um exemplo completo, para eu entender melhor?